# Convert the existing nested dictionary output in string to a list to iterate over it

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a rest api which provides a list of key value pair's and we need to fetch all the id's from this json output file.

Contents of the json file

```
{
    "count": 6,
    "results": [
        {
            "key": "roles",
            "id": "1586230"
        },
        {
            "key": "roles",
            "id": "1586951"
        },
        {
            "key": "roles",
            "id": "1586932"
        },
    ],
    "roles": {
        "1586230": {
            "name": "Systems Engineer",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2022-04-22T03:22:24-07:00",
            "updated_at": "2022-04-22T03:22:24-07:00",
            "id": "1586230"
        },
        "1586951": {
            "name": "Engineer- Software",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2022-05-05T01:51:29-07:00",
            "updated_at": "2022-05-05T01:51:29-07:00",
            "id": "1586951"
        },
        "1586932": {
            "name": "Engineer- SW",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2022-05-05T01:38:37-07:00",
            "updated_at": "2022-05-05T01:38:37-07:00",
            "id": "1586932"
        },
    },
    "meta": {
        "count": 6,
        "page_count": 5,
        "page_number": 1,
        "page_size": 20
    }
}
```

The rest call saves the contents to a file called p1234.json Opened the file in python:

```
with open ('p1234.json') as file:
    data2 = json.load(file)

for ids in data2['results']:
    res= ids['id']
    print(res)
```

Similarly

```
with open ('p1234.json') as file:
    data2 = json.load(file)

for role in data2['roles']:
    res= roles['name']
    print(res)
```

fails with errors.

How to iterate over a nested array do I can only get the values of names listed in roles array

```
roles --> 1586230 --> name --> System Engineer
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop over the items of the dictionary.

```
for key, value in data2['roles'].items():
    res= value['name']
    print(res)
```

Comment: What about the errors in the example json file that keeps it from parsing?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code, I run it and I didn't get any error.
The problem that I see though is your Json file, some commas shouldn't be there:

```
{
"count": 6,
"results": [
    {
        "key": "roles",
        "id": "1586230"
    },
    {
        "key": "roles",
        "id": "1586951"
    },
    {
        "key": "roles",
        "id": "1586932"
    } \\ here
],
"roles": {
    "1586230": {
        "name": "Systems Engineer",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": "2022-04-22T03:22:24-07:00",
        "updated_at": "2022-04-22T03:22:24-07:00",
        "id": "1586230"
    },
    "1586951": {
        "name": "Engineer- Software",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": "2022-05-05T01:51:29-07:00",
        "updated_at": "2022-05-05T01:51:29-07:00",
        "id": "1586951"
    },
    "1586932": {
        "name": "Engineer- SW",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": "2022-05-05T01:38:37-07:00",
        "updated_at": "2022-05-05T01:38:37-07:00",
        "id": "1586932"
    } \\ here 
},
"meta": {
    "count": 6,
    "page_count": 5,
    "page_number": 1,
    "page_size": 20
}
```

after that any parsing function will do the job.

Comment: Good catch on the comma, but you should get an error on the 2nd for loop i.e. `for role in data2['roles']: res= roles['name'] ...`  is incorrect.  It should just be:  `for role in data2['roles']: print(role)` to show ids.

Comment: yeah correct! I tested the first chunk of the code (which works) I didn t pay attention to what's written in the second one. thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: This is printing the ID's which is not what was needed. What i want is the name of the role to be printed. Like Engineer- Software/Engineer- SW. which the above line does not provide